# javax.el.ELException: Cannot convert abcCache of type class java.lang.String to class java.lang.Class

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc

I have randomly started to get

> "javax.el.ELException:"

error in jsp pages where we load the Java code.
The same was working earlier but started to give this error randomly. Have tried building with different versions of JDK, tomcat and maven but the problem still persist.
Any leads will be appreciated.
Find the logs below:

> Mar 05, 2014 3:22:31 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher
>   invoke SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
>   javax.el.ELException: Cannot convert abcCache of type
>   class java.lang.String to class java.lang.Class   at
>   org.apache.el.lang.ELSupport.coerceToType(ELSupport.java:420)     at
>   org.apache.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl.coerceToType(ExpressionFactoryImpl.java:47)
>     at javax.el.BeanELResolver.invoke(BeanELResolver.java:469)  at
>   org.apache.jasper.el.JasperELResolver.invoke(JasperELResolver.java:139)
>     at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:173)    at
>   org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:185)
>     at
>   org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.proprietaryEvaluate(PageContextImpl.java:963)
>     at

Comment: `Cannot convert shippingProvidersCache of type class java.lang.String to class java.lang.Class` show the tag where you're handling the `shippingProvidersCache` on the JSP and what kind of a value you're assigning to said variable on your controller.

Comment: Post your code used in JSP that gives this error.

Comment: The block of code in JSP giving the error is below:

<c:forEach items="${cache.getCache('abcCache').someMethod()}"
var="categoryMap">       <optgroup label="${categoryMap.key}">
            <c:forEach items="${categoryMap.value }" var="category">
             <option value="${category.categoryUrl}">${category.categoryName}
              - ${categoryMap.key }</option>
            </c:forEach>
           </optgroup>
          </c:forEach>

In Java I have Cache which does CacheManager.getInstance().getCache(abcCache.class).someMethod()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is with calling **overloaded Java methods** from JSP where the intended method won't be picked.

e.g. Illustration.java

```
getData(String input){
  // Code removed for simplicity 
}
getData(Class input){
  //Code removed for simplicity
}
```

Here, the jsp code ***getData("validInput")*** can pickup the second method with class parameter. Hence, the exception ***Cannot convert abcCache of type*** **class java.lang.String to class java.lang.Class**

Changing the second method to below solves the issue.

```
 getDataFromClass(Class input){
  //Code removed for simplicity
 }
```

The problem might occur randomly with different versions of JDK/Maven/Tomcat.

As a practice, one can think of having methods with different names, if to be used in such cases.