# getting javax.el.ELException: Cannot convert C of type class java.lang.String to class java.lang.Long

Tags: jsp

I have developed my application using 32 bit java . Now I m running my application using 64 bit java. It is showing error javax.el.ELException: Cannot convert 101.0 of type class java.lang.String to class java.lang.Long while trying to load a jsp inboxSearch.jsp.

here is my jsp:

```
<%@ include file="../jsp/include.jsp" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Inbox Pending</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style-ie6.css" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style-ie7.css" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style-ie8.css" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-tablesorter.css" type="text/css">


<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){


    $("#OnTheFlyTable").tablesorter({ 
    widgets: ['zebra'],
            headers: {
            0: {
                sorter: false
            }} 
    });

});



function exportExcel()
{



    var userRole = document.getElementById('userRole').value;

    document.inbox.action="downloadPendingReport.htm?userRole="+userRole;
    document.inbox.submit();


}


function claimItem(WorkflowTxnId,statusItem,vendorMasterId,category){
    //SC:Mudit passing vendormasterid to the jsp
    //alert("statusItem ---workflowid"+statusItem+"---"+WorkflowTxnId);
    //alert("vendorMasterId is"+vendorMasterId);
//EC:Mudit


    //alert("in inbox search vendorMasterId is"+vendorMasterId);
    document.getElementById("darkLayer").style.display ='';
    $.post("claim.htm",{WorkflowTxnId : WorkflowTxnId,statusItem:statusItem,vendorMasterId:vendorMasterId,category : category},
            function(data){

                document.getElementById("darkLayer").style.display ='none';
                $("#dynamicData").html(data);
            }
             );


}
function fetchData(vendorMasterId)
{
    //alert("inside fetch data");

    //alert(vendorMasterId);
    reqType='P';


    window.open("./viewRequestDetails.htm?vendorMasterId="+vendorMasterId+"&reqType="+reqType,"mywindow",'width=800,height=500,left=0,top=100,screenX=0,screenY=100,scrollbars=yes');  



}

function trackItem(vendorMasterId)
{
    //alert("inside fetch data");

    //alert(vendorMasterId);

    window.open("./trackRequestDetails.htm?vendorMasterId="+vendorMasterId,"mywindow",'width=800,height=500,left=0,top=100,screenX=0,screenY=100,scrollbars=yes');  



}

function showApproveLayout(){
    $('#dynamicData').html();

}

function bulkClaim(){

    document.getElementById('srResults').style.display="none";
    document.getElementById('entCmnts').style.display="block";
    document.getElementById('bulkApprove').disabled=false;
    obj=document.getElementById('hideOnBulkAction');
    obj1= document.getElementById('hideTextOnBulkAction');
    var roleName=document.getElementById('roleName').value;

    if(obj.style.display=="block" && obj1.style.display=="none")
    {
        document.getElementById('bulkReject').disabled=true;
        if(roleName=='Bill Verifier')
        {
        document.getElementById('bulkQuery').disabled=true;
        }
        var objChkUserBox=document.getElementsByName("chk_WorkFlowId");
        var ValueString="";
        var i=0;
        var selChked=0;
        for(i=0;i<objChkUserBox.length;i++)
        {
            if(objChkUserBox[i].checked==true)
            {
                ValueString+=objChkUserBox[i].value+",";
            }
            else{
                selChked++;
            }

        }
        if(objChkUserBox.length==selChked)
        {
            var msg1='Please select atleast one checkbox';
            $('#error').html(msg1);     
            document.getElementById('bulkReject').disabled=false;
            document.getElementById('bulkQuery').disabled=false;
            return false;
        }
        $('#error').html("");
        document.getElementById('hdfWorkFlowList').value=ValueString;
        obj.style.display='none';
        obj1.style.display='block';

    }
    else if(obj.style.display=="none" && obj1.style.display=="block")
    {
        var ValueString=document.getElementById('hdfWorkFlowList').value;
        var remark =  document.getElementById('textAreaComment').value;
        var status="Approve";

        if(remark==null || remark=="")
        {
            var msg1='Please enter the Comments.';
            $('#error').html(msg1);             
            return false;
        }


    document.getElementById("darkLayer").style.display ='';
    $.post("bulkclaim.htm",{hdfWorkFlowList:ValueString,status:status,remark:remark},
            function(data){

                document.getElementById("darkLayer").style.display ='none';
                $("#dynamicData").html(data);
            }
             );


    }
}


function bulkRejectClaim(){

    document.getElementById('srResults').style.display="none";
    document.getElementById('entCmnts').style.display="block";

    obj=document.getElementById('hideOnBulkAction');
    obj1= document.getElementById('hideTextOnBulkAction');

    var roleName=document.getElementById('roleName').value;

    if(obj.style.display=="block" && obj1.style.display=="none")
    {
        document.getElementById('bulkApprove').disabled=true;
        if(roleName=='Bill Verifier')
        {
        document.getElementById('bulkQuery').disabled=true;
        }
        var objChkUserBox=document.getElementsByName("chk_WorkFlowId");
        var ValueString="";
        var i=0;
        var selChked=0;
        for(i=0;i<objChkUserBox.length;i++)
        {
            if(objChkUserBox[i].checked==true)
            {
                ValueString+=objChkUserBox[i].value+",";
            }
            else{
                selChked++;
            }

        }
        if(objChkUserBox.length==selChked)
        {
            var msg1='Please select atleast one checkbox';
            $('#error').html(msg1);
            document.getElementById('bulkApprove').disabled=false;  
            document.getElementById('bulkQuery').disabled=false;
            return false;
        }
        $('#error').html("");
        document.getElementById('hdfWorkFlowList').value=ValueString;
        obj.style.display='none';
        obj1.style.display='block';

    }
    else if(obj.style.display=="none" && obj1.style.display=="block")
    {
        var ValueString=document.getElementById('hdfWorkFlowList').value;
        var remark =  document.getElementById('textAreaComment').value;
        var status="Reject";

        if(remark==null || remark=="")
        {
            var msg1='Please enter the Comments.';
            $('#error').html(msg1);             
            return false;
        }

        document.getElementById("darkLayer").style.display ='';
    $.post("bulkRejectclaim.htm",{hdfWorkFlowList:ValueString,status:status,remark:remark},
            function(data){

                document.getElementById("darkLayer").style.display ='none';
                $("#dynamicData").html(data);
            }
             );

    }


}


function bulkReturnClaim(){

    document.getElementById('srResults').style.display="none";
    document.getElementById('entCmnts').style.display="block";

    obj=document.getElementById('hideOnBulkAction');
    obj1= document.getElementById('hideTextOnBulkAction');
    if(obj.style.display=="block" && obj1.style.display=="none")
    {
        document.getElementById('bulkApprove').disabled=true;
        document.getElementById('bulkReject').disabled=true;
        var objChkUserBox=document.getElementsByName("chk_WorkFlowId");

        var ValueString="";
        var i=0;
        var selChked=0;
        for(i=0;i<objChkUserBox.length;i++)
        {
            if(objChkUserBox[i].checked==true)
            {
                ValueString+=objChkUserBox[i].value+",";
            }
            else{
                selChked++;
            }

        }

        if(objChkUserBox.length==selChked)
        {
            var msg1='Please select atleast one checkbox';
            $('#error').html(msg1);
            document.getElementById('bulkApprove').disabled=false;  
            document.getElementById('bulkReject').disabled=false;
            return false;
        }
        $('#error').html("");
        document.getElementById('hdfWorkFlowList').value=ValueString;

        document.getElementById('queryRow').style.display='block';
        document.getElementById('enterCommentsText').style.display='block';
        obj.style.display='none';
        obj1.style.display='block';

    }

    else if(obj.style.display=="none" && obj1.style.display=="block")
    {

        var ValueString=document.getElementById('hdfWorkFlowList').value;
        var query=document.getElementById('queryFor').value;
        var remark =  document.getElementById('textAreaComment').value;
        var status="Reject";
        var length = remark.length;

        if(query==null || query=="")
        {
            alert('Please select the Query Reason');
            return false;
        }

        if(remark==null || remark=="")
        {

            msg1='Please enter the Comments.';
            $('#error').html(msg1);             
            return false;
        }

        if (length >= 300) 
        {
            msg1='Please enter max. 300 characters';
            $('#error').html(msg1);             
            return false;

        }
        var bulkReturn=document.getElementById("bulkReturn").value="bulkReturn";
        //alert('claiming');
        document.getElementById("darkLayer").style.display ='';
        $.post("bulkReturnclaim.htm",{hdfWorkFlowList:ValueString,status:status,remark:remark,query:query,bulkReturn:bulkReturn},
                function(data){

                    document.getElementById("darkLayer").style.display ='none';
                    $("#dynamicData").html(data);
                }
                 );

    }


}


function selectAll(){
    //alert("In the select all functionality");
    var selectall = document.getElementsByName("selectall"); 
    //alert("selectall "+selectall);
    var checkboxArray = document.getElementsByName('chk_WorkFlowId'); 
    //alert("checkBoxArray "+checkboxArray);
    if(selectall[0].checked == true)
    { 
        for(var i = 0 ; i<checkboxArray.length; i++)
        { 
            checkboxArray[i].checked=true; 
            //alert(checkboxArray[i].toString); 
        } 
    }
    else
    { 
        for(var j = 0 ; j<checkboxArray.length; j++)
        { 
            checkboxArray[j].checked=false; 
        } 
    } 
}
function updateDetails(WorkflowTxnId,statusItem,vendorMasterId){
//  alert("Binal statusItem ---workflowid"+statusItem+"---"+WorkflowTxnId);
//  alert("vendorMasterId is"+vendorMasterId);

    $('#inboxView').load('updateRequestDetails.htm',{WorkflowTxnId : WorkflowTxnId,statusItem:statusItem,vendorMasterId:vendorMasterId}); 

}

function getStartIndexForPaging(currentPage,limit,isPrevOrNext)
{

            var startIndex =0;
            if(isPrevOrNext == 'next')
            {
                  pageNumberToVisit = Number(currentPage)+1;
            }
            else
            {
                  pageNumberToVisit = Number(currentPage) - 1;
            }

                if(Number(pageNumberToVisit) == 1)
                {
                        startIndex = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    startIndex = ((Number(pageNumberToVisit)-1)* Number(limit));    
                }

                return startIndex+"~"+pageNumberToVisit;

}
function getNextOrPreviousPageAudit(isPrevOrNext)
{




     var limit=$.trim($("#limit").val());
     var startIndex=$.trim($("#startIndex").val());
     var totalcount=$.trim($("#count").val());
     var currentPage = $.trim($("#currentPage").val());



        var fromDate=$.trim($("#hdfFromDate").val());
        var toDate=$.trim($("#hdfToDate").val());
        var reqId=$.trim($("#hdfReqId").val());
        var category=$.trim($("#hdfCategory").val());
        var userId=$.trim($("#hdfUserId").val());
        var expenseGL=$.trim($("#hdfExpenseGL").val());
        var evpName=$.trim($("#hdfEvpName").val());
        var vendorMstr=$.trim($("#hdfVendorMstr").val());
        var billNo=$.trim($("#hdfBillNo").val());
        var billDate=$.trim($("#hdfBillDate").val());
        var branch=$.trim($("#hdfBranch").val());
        var requestor=$.trim($("#hdfRequestor").val());
        var status = $.trim($("#status").val());

        //alert('1hi');
     //alert('currnet page is : '+currentPage);
    //alert('StartIndex before: '+startIndex);
    //alert('totalPages before: '+totalPages);

            var parmString = getStartIndexForPaging(currentPage,limit,isPrevOrNext);
            //alert(parmString);
            var parmStringArray = parmString.split("~");
            var startIndex = parmStringArray[0];
            var currentPage = parmStringArray[1];
            //alert('current page  after increment is : '+incrementedCurrentPage);
            //alert('StartIndex after: '+startIndex);
            //alert('Limit after: '+startIndex+"****"+currentPage+"******"+totalcount);

            if(status=="P")
            {
                document.getElementById("darkLayer").style.display ='';
                $.post("searchPendingResult.htm",{timestamp1 :fromDate,timestamp2: toDate,status:status,requestor:requestor,branch:branch,billDate:billDate,billNo:billNo,vendorMstr:vendorMstr,requestId: reqId,evpName:evpName,expenseGL:expenseGL,category:category,userId:userId,totalcount: totalcount,startIndex: startIndex,paging:"yes",currentPage:currentPage},
                        function(data){
                            document.getElementById("darkLayer").style.display ='none';
                            $("#inboxView").html(data);
                        }
                         );
            }
            else
            {
            document.getElementById("darkLayer").style.display ='';
            $.post("searchResult.htm",{timestamp1 :fromDate,timestamp2: toDate,status:status,requestor:requestor,branch:branch,billDate:billDate,billNo:billNo,vendorMstr:vendorMstr,requestId: reqId,evpName:evpName,expenseGL:expenseGL,category:category,userId:userId,totalcount: totalcount,startIndex: startIndex,paging:"yes",currentPage:currentPage},
            function(data){
                document.getElementById("darkLayer").style.display ='none';
                $("#inboxView").html(data);
            }
             );
            } 
             // $('#inboxView').load('searchResult_cc.htm',{fromDate :fromDate,toDate: toDate,requestId: reqId,noticeRegion:region,totalcount: totalcount,startIndex: startIndex,paging:"yes",currentPage:currentPage});


}


</script>
</head>
<body>

<form method="post">

<c:if test="${itemList ne null}">

<fieldset style="max-height:400px;overflow-x:auto;overflow-y:auto;">
<div id="srResults" style="display:block"><legend > Search Results</legend></div>

<c:set var="itemVO" scope="request" value="${itemList}"/>

<div id="hideOnBulkAction" style="display: block;">
<table >
    <tr>
        <c:if
            test="${sessionScope.totalCount gt 0}">
            <td><c:choose>
                <c:when
                    test="${sessionScope.previousPagePresent eq null || sessionScope.previousPagePresent eq 'N'}">

                        <input type="button" class="formbutton" size="6"  value="Previous" style="padding: 1px 2px;" id="previousButton" onclick="getNextOrPreviousPageAudit('previous')" alt="Previous"  disabled />
                </c:when>
                <c:otherwise>
                        <input type="button" class="formbutton" size="6" value="Previous" style="padding: 1px 2px;" id="previousButton1" onclick="getNextOrPreviousPageAudit('previous')"  alt="Previous"  />
                </c:otherwise>

                </c:choose>

            <span style="vertical-align: top; border-right: 0px; border-left: 0px; font-size: 13px; font-weight: solid; font-family: Tahoma; color: #0062AF" >
             Page <label id="currentPageNoLabel" >${sessionScope.currentPage}</label> of ${sessionScope.totalPages}</span>

            <c:choose>
                <c:when
                    test="${sessionScope.nextPagePresent eq null || sessionScope.nextPagePresent eq 'N'}">
                    <input type="button" class="formbutton" value="Next" size="6" style="padding: 1px 2px;" id="nextButton" onclick="getNextOrPreviousPageAudit('next')" alt="Next" disabled />
                </c:when>
                <c:otherwise>

                        <input type="button" class="formbutton" value="Next" size="6" style="padding: 1px 2px;"  id="nextButton" onclick="getNextOrPreviousPageAudit('next')" alt="Next" />
                </c:otherwise>
            </c:choose>
        </td>
        </c:if>

    </tr>
</table>


<c:if test='${listPresent eq "Exists"}'>

    <c:if test="${itemList ne null}">
        <div id="notFoundInward">
            <c:if test="${notFound ne ':'}">
                <p style="color:red"><b>Request Id ${notFound} is/are not found. </b></p> 
            </c:if>
        </div>
        <div id="OnTheFlyTableDiv" style=" width:100%;">
        <table border = "1" id="OnTheFlyTable"  bordercolor="#BECEDB" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1">
            <thead style="background-color: #BECEDB;">
            <tr>
                <th>Select <input type='checkbox' name='selectall' onClick='selectAll()' /></th>
                <th>Sr.No</th>
                <th>Entry Time</th>
                <th>From </th>
                <th>Inward No</th>
                <th>Gross Bill Amount</th>              
                <th>Net Amount</th>
                <th>Category</th>
                <th>User ID</th>
                <th>Expense GL</th>
                <th>Employee/Vendor/<br>Petty Cash Name</th>
                <th>Vendor Master</th>
                <th>Bill No</th>
                <th>Bill Date</th>
                <th>Branch</th>
                <th>Action</th>
                <th>View Details</th>
                <th>Track Workflow</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>

    <c:set var="serialNO" scope="session" value="${startIndex}" />
    <c:forEach var="itemVO" items="${itemList}" varStatus="loopStatus" >
    <c:set var="srNO" scope="session" value="${serialNO+loopStatus.count}" />
        <tr class="${loopStatus.index % 2 == 0 ? 'even' : 'odd'}">

            <td>
                <c:choose>
                    <c:when test='${itemVO.pending_with ne "role"}'>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="chk_WorkFlowId" id="${itemVO.requestId}" value='<c:out value = "InProgress_${itemVO.requestId}" />'/>
                    </c:when>
                    <c:otherwise>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="chk_WorkFlowId" id="${itemVO.requestId}" value='<c:out value = "Claim_${itemVO.requestId}" />'/>
                    </c:otherwise>
                </c:choose>
        </td>
        <c:if test="${sessionScope.currentPage eq 1}">
        <td>&nbsp;${loopStatus.count }</td>
        </c:if>
        <c:if test="${sessionScope.currentPage ne 1}">
        <td>&nbsp;${srNO} </td>
        </c:if>
        <td>&nbsp;${itemVO.updated_date }</td>
        <td>&nbsp;${itemVO.updated_by} </td>
        <td>&nbsp;${itemVO.requestId }</td>
        <c:if test='${itemVO.grossBillAmt eq 0}'>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </c:if>
        <c:if test='${itemVO.grossBillAmt ne 0}'>
            <td>&nbsp;${itemVO.grossBillAmt} </td>
        </c:if>

        <td>&nbsp;${itemVO.netAmount} </td>
        <td>&nbsp;${itemVO.category} </td>
        <td>&nbsp;${itemVO.userId} </td>

        <c:if test='${itemVO.gl_name eq null}'>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </c:if>
        <c:if test='${itemVO.gl_name ne null}'>
        <td>&nbsp;${itemVO.gl_name} </td>
        </c:if>

        <td>&nbsp;${itemVO.employeeName} </td>

        <c:if test='${itemVO.vendorName eq null}'>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </c:if>
        <c:if test='${itemVO.vendorName ne null}'>
        <td>&nbsp;${itemVO.vendorName} </td>
        </c:if>

        <c:if test='${itemVO.billNo eq 0}'>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </c:if>
        <c:if test='${itemVO.billNo ne 0}'>
            <td>&nbsp;${itemVO.billNo} </td>
        </c:if>

        <c:if test='${itemVO.billDate eq null}'>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </c:if>
        <c:if test='${itemVO.billDate ne null}'>
            <td>&nbsp;${itemVO.billDate} </td>
        </c:if>

        <td>&nbsp;${itemVO.branch} </td>


        <td>
        <c:choose>
            <c:when test="${itemVO.isClaimable eq false}">
                <c:set var="statusButton" value="In Progress" />
                <input type="button" class="submitLink" style="color: #008000;" onclick="claimItem('${itemVO.wtxnId}','${itemVO.isClaimable}','${itemVO.requestId}','${itemVO.category}')" 
                    value='<c:out value="${statusButton}"/>'/>
            </c:when>

            <c:otherwise>
                <c:set var="statusButton" value="Claim" />
                <input type="button" class="submitLink" style="color: #CC0000;" onclick="claimItem('${itemVO.wtxnId}','${itemVO.isClaimable}','${itemVO.requestId}','${itemVO.category}')" 
            value='<c:out value="${statusButton}"/>'/>
            </c:otherwise>
        </c:choose>


        </td>
        <td> <input type="button" class="submitLink" style="color: #CC0000;" value="View Details" onclick="fetchData('${itemVO.requestId}')"> </td>

        <td>
        <input type="button" class="submitLink"  style="color: #CC0000;" onclick="trackItem('${itemVO.requestId}')" value="Track Workflow"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>
<br><br>
</div>
<br>
<br>
</div>

<div id="hideTextOnBulkAction" style="display:none;">

<legend id="entCmnts" style="display:none">Enter Comments</legend>
<table width="100%">

<c:set var="queryList" scope="session" value="${queryList}"></c:set>
<c:if test="${roleName eq 'Bill Verifier' }">
<tr id="queryRow" style="display:none">
    <td align="left" style="width:70px"><strong>Query For</strong></td>
    <td align="left" style="width:500px;">
        <select name="queryFor" id="queryFor" >
            <option value="">Select</option>
            <c:forEach var="qList" items="${queryList}">
            <option value="<c:out value="${qList.query}"/>"><c:out value="${qList.query}"/></option>
            </c:forEach>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
</c:if>

<tr id="enterCommentsText" style="display:none;"> 
<td align="left" style="width:100px"><strong>Enter Comments:</strong></td><td></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td colspan="2">
    <textarea rows="10" cols="150"  name="textAreaComment" id="textAreaComment"></textarea>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>


</c:if>
</c:if>


<c:if test='${listPresent eq "Not Exists"}'>

Nothing found to display
</c:if>

<input type="hidden" value="${keyVO}" name="hdfkeyVO"/>
<input type="hidden" id="hdfWorkFlowList" name="hdfWorkFlowList" value=""/>
<input type="hidden" id="bulkReturn" name="bulkReturn" value=""/>


<input type="hidden" name="queryList" id="queryList" value="${sessionScope.queryList}"/>
<input type="hidden" name="roleName" id="roleName" value="${roleName}"/>
<input type="hidden" name="status" id="status" value="${sessionScope.status}"/>
<input type="hidden" name="limit" id="limit" value="${sessionScope.limit}"/>
<input type="hidden" name="startIndex" id="startIndex" value="${sessionScope.startIndex}"/>
<input type="hidden" name="count" id="count" value="${sessionScope.totalCount}"/>
<input type="hidden" name="currentPage" id="currentPage" value="${sessionScope.currentPage}"/>
<input type="hidden" name="totalPages" id="totalPages" value="${sessionScope.totalPages}"/>

<input type="hidden" name="hdfFromDate" id="hdfFromDate" value="${sessionScope.timestampFromDate}"/>
<input type="hidden" name="hdfToDate" id="hdfToDate" value="${sessionScope.timestampToDate}"/>
<input type="hidden" name="hdfReqId" id="hdfReqId" value="${sessionScope.requestId}"/>
<input type="hidden" name="hdfRequestor" id="hdfRequestor" value="${sessionScope.requestor}"/>
<input type="hidden" name="hdfCategory" id="hdfCategory" value="${sessionScope.category}"/>
<input type="hidden" name="hdfUserId" id="hdfUserId" value="${sessionScope.userID}"/>
<input type="hidden" name="hdfExpenseGL" id="hdfExpenseGL" value="${sessionScope.expenseGL}"/>
<input type="hidden" name="hdfEvpName" id="hdfEvpName" value="${sessionScope.evpName}"/>
<input type="hidden" name="hdfVendorMstr" id="hdfVendorMstr" value="${sessionScope.vendorMstr}"/>
<input type="hidden" name="hdfBillNo" id="hdfBillNo" value="${sessionScope.billNo}"/>
<input type="hidden" name="hdfBillDate" id="hdfBillDate" value="${sessionScope.billDate}"/>
<input type="hidden" name="hdfBranch" id="hdfBranch" value="${sessionScope.branch}"/>
 <input type="hidden" name="userRole" id="userRole" value="${sessionScope.userRole }">


<div id="error" class="error" style="color: red">

</div>

</fieldset>
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<input type="button" id="bulkApprove" class="formbutton" name="Bulk Approve" value="Bulk Approve" onclick="javascript: bulkClaim()"/>
<input type="button" id="bulkReject" class="formbutton" name="Bulk Reject" value="Bulk Reject" onclick="javascript: bulkRejectClaim()"/>
 <input type="button" value="Export Excel Pending Report" class="formbutton" name="" onclick="exportExcel()"/>
<c:if test="${roleName eq 'Bill Verifier' }">
<input type="button" id="bulkQuery" class="formbutton" name="Bulk Query" value="Bulk Query" onclick="javascript: bulkReturnClaim()"/>
</c:if>
</td>
</tr>

</table>
</c:if>



</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Can you help me..

Comment: possible duplicate of [javax.el.ELException: Cannot convert abcCache of type class java.lang.String to class java.lang.Class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22201082/javax-el-elexception-cannot-convert-abccache-of-type-class-java-lang-string-to)

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you have any overloaded method being called from your JSP.
I faced a similar problem and fixed it by changing the name of one of the overloaded Java method being called from JSP.

You can refer to [javax.el.ELException: Cannot convert abcCache of type class java.lang.String to class java.lang.Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22201082/javax-el-elexception-cannot-convert-abccache-of-type-class-java-lang-string-to).

See [this](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=55483) for more details of the bug.

Hope it helps.